# Neo4j, Which is better: multiple relationships or one with a property?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j, and I'm building a social network. For the sake of this question, my graph consists of `user` and `event` nodes with relationship(s) between them.

A user may be invited, join, attend or host an event, and each is a subset of the one before it.

Is there any benefit to / should I create multiple relationships for each status/state, or one relationship with a property to store the current state?

Comment: i think for the sake of simple programming code you should use one relationship type (e.g. "EVENT") and its property (e.g. "status:attend"). but if you really must max the speed please use the relationship types as suggested below

Answer (score 2):

Graph-type queries are more easily/efficiently done on relationship types than properties, from what I understand.

How about one relationship, but a different relationship type?

You can query on several types of relationships with pipes using Cypher (in case you have other relationships to the event that you don't want to pick up in queries).

Update--adding console example: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=woe684

Alternatively, you can just leave the old relationships there and not have to build the slightly more complicated queries, but that feels a bit wasteful for this use case.

Comment: Do you know if this performance difference is still true today?
I have 8 different relationships, with 5 levels each. Should I still create 40 different relationship types rather than 8 with a 'value' property?

Comment: Yes. In cache and storage the relationship type is basically the way it's indexed. If you only have 8 different relationships it doesn't matter, but if you have (on a given node) a few thousand EVENT_ATTENDEE relationships and 100 EVENT_HOST relationships (as per this example), specifying EVENT_HOST it won't even consider the other relationship types. As you have more relationships it will matter more.

Answer (score 2):

When possible, choosing different relationship types over a single type qualified by properties can have a significant positive performance impact when querying the graph. The former approach is aways at least 2x faster than the latter. When data is in high-level cache and the graph is queried using native Java API, the first approach is more than 8x faster for single-hop traversals.

Source: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/24/neo4j-qualifying-relationships.html

Comment: It juste when the relationship without properties but how about performance when it contains attributes?